# AWS MySQL RDS can't create new DB user while having ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-rds

Using my Ubuntu terminal `mysql`, I have successfully connected to AWS MySQL RDS instance using my `master_account` account and yet, when I run the standard

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

I'm getting the typical `ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation` error message.

When I run `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'master_account'`, I get:

```
+-----------------------------+
| Grants for master_account@%                                                        
|
+-----------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'master_account'@'%'                                         
|
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 
'master_account'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------+
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what the issue is as the `'master_account` has all privileges, and therefore, I should be able to create new users?

BTW, this RDS instance has been `PROMOTED` from a read replica for development purposes. Would that be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that while I was logged in with a `USERNAME` that has all the privileges to manage this specific `database`, I was not logged in with the AWS `MASTER USERNAME` that has the privileges to manage DB users.

BTW the `MASTER USERNAME` is listed in your RDS console under the `Configuration` tab.